# Enthought Mayavi Animation Blank Display

Tags: python, pip, enthought, mayavi

I have been attempting to run the following python code (from Enthought's website) to test the animation capabilities of Enthought's Mayavi module.

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy
n_mer, n_long = 6, 11
pi = numpy.pi
dphi = pi/1000.0
phi = numpy.arange(0.0, 2*pi + 0.5*dphi, dphi, 'd')
mu = phi*n_mer
x = numpy.cos(mu)*(1+numpy.cos(n_long*mu/n_mer)*0.5)
y = numpy.sin(mu)*(1+numpy.cos(n_long*mu/n_mer)*0.5)
z = numpy.sin(n_long*mu/n_mer)*0.5

# View it.
l = mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, numpy.sin(mu), tube_radius=0.025, colormap='Spectral')

# Now animate the data.
ms = l.mlab_source
for i in range(10):
    x = numpy.cos(mu)*(1+numpy.cos(n_long*mu/n_mer +
                                  numpy.pi*(i+1)/5.)*0.5)
    scalars = numpy.sin(mu + numpy.pi*(i+1)/5.)
    ms.set(x=x, scalars=scalars)
```

However, upon execution, nothing happens.  It runs without errors but only the TVTK Scene window pops up blank - no image, no animation.  Could the problem lie in the Mayavi module import?  The example on the website starts with:
    from enthought.mayavi import mlab
whereas, I have:
    from mayavi import mlab
The 'enthought.mayavi' import string does not work for me.  The Mayavi I'm using is a pip installation.
What should I do to fix this?  I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.2.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This demo works on my machine (just upgraded to OS 10.8.2).

First thing, though, is to answer your question about the import. Some time around a year and a half ago, we refactored the packages to remove the enthought name from the imports. Thus, the standard way to import mayavi's mlab changed from

```
from enthought.mayavi import mlab
```

to

```
from mayavi import mlab
```

The setup is designed so that the former still works, but we have attempted to refactor the imports in our example code to the second pattern. Therefore, we can be pretty sure it's not a problem with the import statement.

Have you gotten anything to run in Mayavi yet? Try this:

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.test_plot3d()
```

Also, what is the version of mayavi, which EPD do you have (32- or 64-bit), and what is the result of the following, in Terminal?

```
$ echo $ETS_TOOLKIT
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,
I tried the test code:
    from mayavi import mlab
    mlab.test_plot3d()
It produces a blank TVTK window with the mouse pointer indicating something is loading but nothing ever does.

Comment: The mayavi version I have is 4.2.0, installed via pip.  The $ETS_TOOLKIT variable is empty.

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using? If wx, what version? How did you build VTK? Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Python? I've seen something like this happen when you are using a Cocoa-based GUI toolkit (wx 2.9.x, most Qt builds nowadays or anything 64-bit) with a Carbon-based VTK build. You need to use either all-Carbon or all-Cocoa.

Comment: You can check your VTK install like so:  
> `otool -L /<path to VTK libraries>/libvtkRendering.dylib | grep Carbon`

Comment: I appreciate if you can direct me to some info. On OSX When I run the example from IPython it works great, but only when I try using it inside Spyder it shows the hourglass and does nothing (hangs), I would like to keep everything in Spyder.

Comment: Ok I found answer to my question! I only had to select Qt backend for IPython graphics (in Prefrences/IPython console/Graphics),the default is inline.

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your original question to include the important note that you were doing this in IPython, it sounds like an IPython notebook or QTconsole.

Answer (score 0):

Using Canopy on Win 7 64 I had a similar problem. Only it displayed the last frame, no animation. I fixed it by changing the pylab backend to wx instead of qt.